# What is the difference between "thief" and "burglar"?

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between "thief" and "burglar" in meaning?

Comment: could you include dictionary definitions, this WOULD help you

Comment: @WendyG - It would not only help the OP, it would help the entire community. Why should several of us go scurrying for dictionaries. As our ["Details, please..."](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) meta post says: _Including a definition serves a couple different purposes: (a) it shows you've put forth a good-faith effort to answer your own question, and (b) it saves time for people answering your question, because they don't have to spend time writing things that you already know while they are composing their answers._

Answer (score 2):

A burglar specifically describes someone who *breaks in* to a building, such as your home, to steal something. The act of breaking and entering to steal is called "burglary".

A thief is someone who performs any kind of theft, usually by stealth, such as taking your wallet from your pocket. It doesn't *necessarily* involve breaking and entering. You could say that a burglar is a *specific kind of thief*.

When theft is carried out using force or threats this is usually called a *mugging* and the person who carries out such a crime is a *mugger*.